# Prove there is a unique set $A$ such that for every set $B$, $A \cup B=B$ using Natural Deduction.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification, first-order-logic, natural-deduction

I added $\forall Y(\emptyset \cup Y = Y)$ as a premise; the exercise does not provide it.

$
\def\fitch#1#2{\quad\begin{array}{|l}#1\\\hline#2\end{array}}
\def\Ae#1{\qquad\mathbf{\forall E} \: #1 \\}
\def\Ai#1{\qquad\mathbf{\forall I} \: #1 \\}
\def\Ee#1{\qquad\mathbf{\exists E} \: #1 \\}
\def\Ei#1{\qquad\mathbf{\exists I} \: #1 \\}
\def\R#1{\qquad\mathbf{R} \: #1 \\}
\def\ci#1{\qquad\mathbf{\land I} \: #1 \\}
\def\ce#1{\qquad\mathbf{\land E} \: #1 \\}
\def\ii#1{\qquad\mathbf{\to I} \: #1 \\}
\def\ie#1{\qquad\mathbf{\to E} \: #1 \\}
\def\be#1{\qquad\mathbf{\leftrightarrow E} \: #1 \\}
\def\bi#1{\qquad\mathbf{\leftrightarrow I} \: #1 \\}
\def\qi#1{\qquad\mathbf{=I}\\}
\def\qe#1{\qquad\mathbf{=E} \: #1 \\}
\def\ne#1{\qquad\mathbf{\neg E} \: #1 \\}
\def\ni#1{\qquad\mathbf{\neg I} \: #1 \\}
\def\IP#1{\qquad\mathbf{IP} \: #1 \\}
\def\x#1{\qquad\mathbf{X} \: #1 \\}
\def\DNE#1{\qquad\mathbf{DNE} \: #1 \\}
$
$
\fitch{1.\, \forall Y(\emptyset \cup Y = Y)}{
  2.\, \exists X\forall Y(X \cup Y = Y) \Ei{1}
  \fitch{3.\, \forall Y(C \cup Y=Y)}{
       \fitch{4.\, \forall Y(D \cup Y=Y)}{
         5.\, C \cup D=D \Ae{3}
         6.\, D \cup C = C \Ae{4}
         \vdots\\
         C = D
        }\\
        \forall Y(D \cup Y=Y) \to C=D\\
        \forall Z(\forall Y(Z \cup Y=Y) \to C=Z)\\
        k. \forall Y(C \cup Y=Y) \land \forall Z(\forall Y(Z \cup Y=Y) \to C=Z) \ci{4,k}
        k+1.\, \exists X[\forall Y(X \cup Y=Y) \land \forall Z(\forall Y(Z \cup Y=Y) \to X=Z] \Ei{k+1}
        }\\
        \exists X[\forall Y(X \cup Y=Y) \land \forall Z(\forall Y(Z \cup Y=Y) \to X=Z] \Ee{3-k+1}
}
$

Is this proof skeleton correct ? Am I going in a good direction ?

EDIT:

Following advice in the comments, I made another version including 3 axioms as premises and deriving $\forall Y(\emptyset \cup Y = Y)$. I omitted the instantiation of the axioms. Going to include it in a final version.

$
\fitch{1.\, \forall x\neg(x \in \emptyset)\\2.\,\forall A\forall B \forall x(x \in A \cup B \leftrightarrow a \in A \lor a \in B)\\3.\,\forall A\forall B(\forall x(x \in A \leftrightarrow x \in B) \to A=B)}{
 \fitch{4.\, a \in \emptyset \cup A}{
 5.\, a \in \emptyset \lor a \in A \\
 6.\, \neg(a \in \emptyset)\\
 7.\,a \in A
}\\
\fitch{8.\, a \in A}{
 9.\, a \in A\\
 10.\,a \in \emptyset \lor a \in A\\
 11.\,a \in \emptyset \cup A
}\\
12.\, a \in \emptyset \cup A \leftrightarrow a \in A\\
13.\,\, \forall Y(\emptyset \cup Y=\emptyset) \\
14.\, \exists X\forall Y(X \cup Y=X) \\
\fitch{\forall Y(C \cup Y=Y)}{
       \fitch{4.\, \forall Y(D \cup Y=Y)}{
         5.\, C \cup D=D \Ae{3}
         6.\, D \cup C = C \Ae{4}
         \vdots\\
         C = D
        }\\
        \forall Y(D \cup Y=Y) \to C=D\\
        \forall Z(\forall Y(Z \cup Y=Y) \to C=Z)\\
        k. \forall Y(C \cup Y=Y) \land \forall Z(\forall Y(Z \cup Y=Y) \to C=Z)
        k+1.\, \exists X[\forall Y(X \cup Y=Y) \land \forall Z(\forall Y(Z \cup Y=Y) \to X=Z] \Ei{}
        }\\
        \exists X[\forall Y(X \cup Y=Y) \land \forall Z(\forall Y(Z \cup Y=Y) \to X=Z] \Ee{}
}
$

P.S.: It is Example 3.6.2 of the book "How to Prove It" by Daniel Velleman.

Comment: $\forall Y~(\emptyset\cup Y=Y)$ should not be a premise but something which you derive from the **axiom of empty set**: $\exists S\forall T~\neg(T\in S)$

Comment: Which axioms of set theory are you allowed to use?

Comment: Thank you, @Graham Kemp. That's exactly what I was looking for. How would you derive it ? Any hint ?

Comment: @Taroccoesbrocco, the exercise does not clarify which axioms I am allowed to use. But I suppose the axiom Graham suggests and equality of sets.

Comment: I would suppose it depends on whether $\emptyset$, $\cup$ are functional symbols in the language or not.  If they are, then probably the relevant axioms would be empty set $\forall x, \lnot(x \in \emptyset)$, union $\forall A \forall B \forall x, x \in A \cup B \leftrightarrow x \in A \vee x \in B$, and extensionality $\forall A \forall B, (\forall x, x \in A \leftrightarrow x \in B) \rightarrow A = B$.

Comment: Thank you, @Daniel Schepler. Going to rework it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a proof in Fitch. I used $e$ for the empty set. Unfortunately this software does not have $\cup$ as a built-in symbol so I had to use my own $union$ function symbol.

I think the only tricky part may be the use of $=$ Elim on line 31:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much ! Your proof is great !

Comment: One question: In steps 24 thru 31, are you working with the empty set and an arbitrary set _a_ ?

Comment: @F.Zer Yes. $e$ is the empty set, and $a$ is an arbitrary set ... $a$ is introduced in line 19, and since it is a 'new' constant, it takes the role of an arbitrary object, which is why on line 37 you can do a universal introduction

Answer (score 1):

Clearly empty set $\cup$ A = A for all sets A.
Assume for all sets A, E $\cup$ A = A.
Thus E = E $\cup$ empty set = empty set.

Exercise.  Prove the dual theorem that
the universal set U is the unique set with
U $\cap$ A = A, for all sets A.